# Delete remote repository from git shell

Tags: git, version-control, github, dvcs

I am new to Git and stackoverflow. I just want to ask how to delete a remote repository from git shell as deleting from the web page is a long task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think this is really what you want to do, but to remove a remote repository from your local repository you can do this:

```
git remote remove <remote-name>
```

Note that this will only remove the link you have in your local repository, it will not touch anything wherever your remote repository actually is.

If you want to physically delete it there, you have to do it *there*. This is not something that can—or should—be done from a local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

There is no way to actually delete a repository hosted on github from the git shell without quite complex scripting and actually sending data over HTTP. On a side note the questions you post on SO should show the efforts you have given. Welcome to SO :)